# how to display images in django template

Tags: image, python-2.7, django-1.3

sorry my question is very basic ,I want to display an image in template page,I am working hours for it,The image is not displaying
I create a new project SecondPrjt ,there is only one view function named 'index' and one template named  test.html , and create a folder named static in side SecondPrjt  folder
and create folder images in it and place all needed images there

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'SecondPrjt.views.home', name='home'),
     (r'^$','views.index'),
    .........
)   

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('test.html')
```

**test.html:**

```
img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/img03.jpg" width="186" height="186"
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = "C:/wamp/www/SecondPrjt/static" 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "C:/wamp/www/SecondPrjt/static",
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

Can any one suggest whats wrong with me.**Note**I am using **windows** and **django1.3** and using development server.Thanks in advance

 I got the following after I request http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in browse

```
c:\wamp\www\SecondPrjt>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'SecondPrjt.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2011 15:18:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 89
[05/Sep/2011 15:18:24] <b>"GET /images/img03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2028
```

Comment: I try to hardcode  test.html like   <img src="C:/wamp/www/SecondPrjt/static/static/img03.jpg" />,This also fails

Comment: When hard coded ,there is no 404 message.But still image not displayed

Comment: Is there any problem in my html sytax?,In internet explorer is works(when hard coded)

Comment: The reason it works in IE but nowhere else when hard-coded is because you need the `file://` syntax... but hard-coding it really tells you nothing other than the fact that the file exists on your computer.

Comment: I tried file:///C:/wamp/www/SecondPrjt/static/images/img03.jpg ,this also fails when I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/. But when simply right click on test.html using mozilla firefox it displays the page with image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all likelihood, your problem is that you've used absolute URLs in both the `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

If you want to include absolute URLs to each static dir (it feels like a hack, but it is fine, as you should only ever use `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in development), then you can fix the issue by simply setting `STATIC_ROOT = ''`.

**Edit**:  Looks like that wasn't your only bug.  In addition, if you take a look at your debug output, you'll notice something strange about the 404 -- it's coming from `/images/img03.jpg`.  If you'll remember, you tried to append `{{ STATIC_URL }}` to that, so it should have been `/static/images/img03.jpg`.

This is because when using `render_to_response`, you never pass any context (so the template never has access to `STATIC_URL` -- it thinks it's blank (hence why you didn't see the `/static/` as part of the image URL.  Whenever you want to use *ANY* context, you *MUST* pass it to the template.  In this case, you should use [`[RequestContext]`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Therefore, you must make sure you have added `django.core.context_processors.static` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in *settings.py*.  You should use `render_to_response` as follows:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('test.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*The following is an explanation of what context processors are*:

In *settings.py*, you then would have something like:

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     'constant_context_processor.constants',
     'django.core.context_processors.static',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.core.context_processors.debug',
     'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
     'django.core.context_processors.media',
     'django.core.context_processors.request', )
```

The important part here is that you have `django.core.context_processors.static`.  In Django, a context processor is a function that returns a context dict.  For instance, in my Django projects, I often use the following code snippet:

*constant_context_processor.py*:

```
import settings
def constants(request):
    return {
           'CONSTANTS': settings.CONSTANTS,
    }
```

(You'll note that above in *settings.py*, I used `constant_context_processor.constants` as one of the context processors).  This allows me to define constants in *settings.py* and to use them in my templates, for instance as something like `{{ CONSTANTS.favicon_url }}`.

As you can see, the advantage to context processors and using `RequestContext` is that context you generally need in your templates gets automatically added, so you don't have to manually populate a dictionary of your context in every view.  Django knows there are certain variables you usually want access to in your templates, so they make them accessible via their context processors (so, for instance, django.core.context_processors.request will give you access to a given request, its GET and POST parameters, and all kinds of metadata from a template, which is often useful if, say, you vary the content based on the GET parameters).

In your case, you didn't want to use much context, but you did want to use a little bit (`{{ STATIC_URL }}`), so you needed at least django.core.context_processors.static.

Comment: Thank u 4 u r response,I still have the problem after I set STATIC_ROOT = '  '.

Comment: @Jisson I have updated it -- it looks like you had a second bug (you weren't passing any context to render_to_response).  I suggest you read my entire answer (though the second half is mostly just a general explanation) and perhaps go to the Django documentation and reading a bit more.  Context and context processors are tricky to understand the first time you encounter them, but they are really important and they are a huge part of Django's power.

Comment: Thanks Thank you very much.I sovle the problem with your help.Actually nowi am studying Django for devlope a web application(considerably large),Which are the best free tutorials other than django project, and djangobook?

Comment: I've always found the django documentation to be fairly comprehensive.  When I started, I just used the "Your first django app" tutorial, then kind of went through the documentation and built a lot of stuff.  I'm not sure about general tutorials, but in my opinion, the Django documentation is some of the best I've ever read.

Comment: Ok thanks Alex C.I have one more doubt,How can I use an image in a css file? Is there any way with out hard code? Now I use as follows,   body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #FFFFFF url(C:/wamp/www/SecondPrjt/static/images/img02.gif) repeat;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #402C16;
}

Comment: You will have to hard-code the name of the image (that one's pretty much unavoidable in any case), but you should be using relative paths; in this case, `url(/static/images/img02.gif)`, just as you would do with any static webserver.  When you actually deploy, as long as you correctly serve static files, you won't need to change any CSS urls.